# array_key_exsists not working as expected PHP

Tags: php, post, array-key-exists

Hi i am using `array_key_exists` in php , here is my code

```
$action_array = array(
    'add_post_ajax'=>'posts'
);


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{ 
     echo $_POST['action'];
    if(array_key_exists($_POST['action'],$action_array))
    {
        $class = $action_array[$_POST['action']];
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "wrong data";
    }
}
```

`echo $_POST['action'];` display `add_post_ajax` , then it prints `wrong data`

strange , please help me ,  am i doing anything wrong here

**UPDATE**

I also tried to trim

```
if(array_key_exists(trim($_POST['action']),$action_array))
```

still the same result :/

here is my ajax request

```
xmlhttp.send("action='add_post_ajax' &name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&post=" + post);
```

`echo $_POST['action']` gives me `add_post_ajax` but `var_dump($_POST['action'])` gives me a wired result

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'&#39;add_post_ajax&#39; '</font> <i>(length=16)</i>
</pre>
```

What is it :o

Comment: Another way to do this is `if(isset($action_array[$_POST['action']]))`

Comment: Works fine for me! Are you sure it return's `add_post_ajax` ?

Comment: yes , i am sure . @JohnConde , i tried your one still the same

Comment: Does this works for you? `$action_array = array(
   'add_post_ajax'=>'posts'
  );

  $_POST['action'] = "add_post_ajax";
 
  if(array_key_exists($_POST['action'],$action_array))
   echo "YES";`

Comment: here is my ajax request xmlhttp.send("action='add_post_ajax' &name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&post=" + post);

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST['action'])` or even `array_keys($_POST['action'])` tell you?

Comment: @MarkFox i have updated my question , please check

Comment: You have the [xdebug extension turned on](http://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-and-profiling-php-with-xdebug/), which adds some html to the output of `var_dump` — more importantly you are not looking for an array key, you are looking for an array value: use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead of `array_key_exists()`

Comment: @MarkFox i need to use array_key_exists here is my planned function   echo "came";
  $class = $action_array[$_POST['action']];
  echo $class;
  require $class.".php";
  $obj = new $class();
  $obj->$_POST['action']();

Comment: check posted data in chrome or firefox network tab! once i have a same problem i think it solved by restarting webserver!

Comment: I'm sorry, I see you are trying to map an a named action to a class value. What's strange is I have no problem running your code, I get the expected result. I'm using PHP's built in webserver, and cURL on the command line — what is your setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is single quotes.

Your $_POST['action'] uses `'add_post_ajax'` but you're checking for `add_post_ajax`

When you send this:

```
xmlhttp.send("action='add_post_ajax' ...
```

you receive this:

```
 &#39;add_post_ajax&#39; (length=16)
```

`add_post_ajax` is 14 characters long, the extra two characters are `&#39;`; it's the html character for a single quote.